# how to set active on angularjs bootstrap tab

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui

am using Angular Bootstrap UI to show a tabset with static content (using AngularUI bootstrap). Here is the plunker link that illustrate my issue http://plnkr.co/edit/n8Xp3GrAqlbNxZ7VrXR6?p=preview

The issue is if I want to set the 1st tab invisible and the 2nd tab visible, it still shows the 1st tab content as active.

I tried to apply active css on the tab, but it does not work:

```
<tabset>
    <tab ng-show="$parent.hideme" ng-class="{active:$parent.hideme}">
        <tab-heading>
            tab1
        </tab-heading>
        <div>
            tab content 1
        </div>
    </tab>
    <tab ng-hide="$parent.hideme" ng-class="{active:!$parent.hideme}">
        <tab-heading>
            tab2
        </tab-heading>
        <div>
            tab content 2
        </div>
    </tab>
</tabset>
```

Any idea to solve the issue?

Comment: `active` on tab.....http://plnkr.co/edit/g2980ehsPWTJzWII05rS?p=preview

Comment: charlietfl: your plunker still show tab2 with tab content1

Comment: figured out how to do it using `disabled` and add a style rule that `disabled` is hidden   http://plnkr.co/edit/g2980ehsPWTJzWII05rS?p=preview

Comment: the tab directive has 'heading,active,disabled,select()' properties. ng-show and ng-hide are angularjs directives,they only support starndard html elments.

Comment: charlietfl: I would like to have the 2nd tab and 2nd tab content showing as active in the first page load, I could not make it work based on your plunker.  Possible for you to make another plunker?

Comment: to simply my question, I made a plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/GJLL1AzncJ1uJTmDMnjZ?p=preview

My question is how to make tab2 and tab content 2 to show as active on the 1st page load?

Answer (score 2):

Even though an old question. I had a fairly similar issue and used `ng-init` to set the `active` attribute.

Using the code supplied:

```
<div ng-init="activeTab = true">
<tabset>
    <tab ng-show="$parent.hideme" ng-class="{active:$parent.hideme}">
        <tab-heading>
            tab1
        </tab-heading>
        <div>
            tab content 1
        </div>
    </tab active="activeTab">
    <tab ng-hide="$parent.hideme" ng-class="{active:!$parent.hideme}">
        <tab-heading>
            tab2
        </tab-heading>
        <div>
            tab content 2
        </div>
    </tab>
</tabset>
</div>
```

[Demo in Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Ylr7UjXlZS5qUXRMrQ02?p=preview)

Of course, instead of using `ng-init`, `activeTab` could be initialized in the controller.